# Could not find method bitwiseNegate() for arguments [] on source set main of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cocos2d-x

I am trying to build Cocos2d-x 3.16 android-studio project by following http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/cocos2d-x/en/installation/Android-Studio.html.

But the gradle build of libcocos2dx module is giving this error -

Error:(14, 0) Could not find method bitwiseNegate() for arguments [] on source set main of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.

on line 14.0 of the following build.gradle file.-

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION.toInteger()
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
            targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    ~
        sourceSets.main {
            aidl.srcDir "../java/src"
            java.srcDir "../java/src"
            manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: '../java/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    }
```

following is the gradle.properties

```
    PROP_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=26
    PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
    PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=27
    PROP_APP_PLATFORM=16
    PROP_APP_ABI=x86
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try to remove this extra `~` line 14 ?
This operator does not have its place here.

Comment: And now, what is on line 14 ?

Comment: I haven't got this to work. Could there be a build tool or NDK version issue?